# Issues with rtl8192cu drivers

Tags: networking, wireless, driver

The Problem:

I am currently having trouble with WiFi drivers on the Raspberry Pi. I am using PiBang  which is built on top of the Wheezy distribution. I have an Edimax nano USB WiFi
   dongle which uses rtl8192cu drivers. The drivers included in the kernel (8192cu) have
   been known to have issues with going into monitor mode (a feature that I need), but work
   very well in most cases. Furthermore, I have noticed that the kernel driver yields
   signal level/strength as a percentage which is completely useless to me, and they fail
   to provide appropriate radio header information through libpcap. The kernel drivers
  in 3.6.11+ and 3.10.25+ both have these issues. I tried to use an alternate driver
  module, rtl8192cu, which was compiled from source from the Realtek site. This driver
  provided signal strength in dBm (from iwlist) and I was able to get radiotap headers
  from libpcap. Unfortunately, this driver had some sort of flaw since the signal strength
  would never deviate from -35 dBm and the MAC addresses I read from packets on the
  network were suspicious (5 - 6 nearly identical addresses with the last hex digit
  changed). My only conclusion is that this driver does not work correctly. My problem
  comes down to this: I need to find rtl8192cu drivers that will provide signal strength
  in dBm and will give me access to radiotap headers through libpcap.

The Big Picture:

I am trying to use a Raspberry Pi to sniff the network and grab WiFi packets from nearby
  devices. These packets will be analyzed to extract signal strengths and MAC addresses.
  The MAC addresses will be used to identify devices and the signal strengths will be used
  to approximate the distance the device is from the Raspberry Pi. My code appears to work
  correctly on my laptop (varying signal strengths for different devices and clearly
  unique MAC addresses), but I can't get any useful data out of the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you have written your code.  If it works, you should get it reviewed over on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).